# Is it possible to change the number of Akka's threads dynamically?

Tags: multithreading, dynamic, akka, threadpool, akka-cluster

**Hello everyone!**

### **A.**

Usually, it's possible to do but does it works fine as well with Akka Framework?

I mean if is it possible to change the number of Akka's threads dynamically?

### **B.**

Another good question is, can I decide how many threads each node will get?

I mean - can i set the number of threads per node at the start?

*Even if you know one answer, bless you!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a little bit more research the answer to those questions is YES.

If someone finds it necessary I found an explanation about it here:

16.4.3. Changing thread pool size statically

https://livebook.manning.com/book/akka-in-action/chapter-16/148